# How to create a Triangle shaped drawing from my variables in Python

Tags: python

I just recently dove in to the world of programming and was given a very basic exercise to complete but I am kind of stuck and do not know what to do next.
The problem was : Given 3 numbers determine if they can form a triangle and if yes calculate the Perimeter and Area,draw the Triangle afterwards.
I have managed to calculate the perimeter and area of the triangle(is such exists) but have no idea how to make the computer draw a triangle from whatever values were input.

Here is the code:

```
import math
a = int(input("Enter your first number"))
b = int(input("Enter your second number"))
c = int(input("Enter your third number"))
if a+b>c and a+c>b and b+c>a:
    print("The Triangle's Perimeter is:")
    print(int(a+b+c))
    print("The Area of the triangle is:")
    print(int(math.sqrt((a+b+c)/2)*(((a+b+c)/2)-a)*(((a+b+c)/2)-b)*(((a+b+c)/2)-c)))
else:
    print("The numbers do not form a triangle")
input("Press any key to continue")
```

Would love if you guys could give me an insight on how to achieve this task

Comment: There are a few built in modules suitable for drawing shapes. Take a look at [turtle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#turtle) or [Tkinter](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/)(the `canvas` widget in particular).

Comment: Thank you for your input,I have looked around but didn't find anything of use.I need to create the triangle shape based on the inputs from a,b and c variables.Do you know a way I can do that?

Comment: What exactly is the question? How to determine the points of the triangle from the side length, or how to draw the triangle using a graphics framework?

Comment: I never used `turtle` of `Tkinter` but there is a whole universe, so to speak, of decent drawing utilities in Python. My favourite is `matplotlib`. I doesn't come with all Python distributions as a standard, but if you have it I can help you in no-time. Try the following line of code: `import maplotlib.pyplot as plt`. If it works for your Python let me know and I can sort something out.

Comment: @tobias_k I'm sorry I cannot explain it better,I have difficulties using english as it is.But here is my question: Suppose the user selects an input value of 4 for the a variable,4 for the b variable and 4 for the c variable.Am I able to graphically draw the triangle from those values.What if the user enters other values for a,b,c.Will the triangle change accordingly.This is where I am stuck.I am able to draw a normale triangle using turtle,but whether the values change or not,it's the same triangle.

Comment: Thank you all,I'll go with a standard drawing.

Answer (score 7):

Here's another solution, using Tkinter:

```
from Tkinter import *

def draw(a, b, c):
    # determine corner points of triangle with sides a, b, c
    A = (0, 0)
    B = (c, 0)
    hc = (2 * (a**2*b**2 + b**2*c**2 + c**2*a**2) - (a**4 + b**4 + c**4))**0.5 / (2.*c)
    dx = (b**2 - hc**2)**0.5
    if abs((c - dx)**2 + hc**2 - a**2) > 0.01: dx = -dx # dx has two solutions
    C = (dx, hc)

    # move away from topleft, scale up a bit, convert to int
    coords = [int((x + 1) * 75) for x in A+B+C]

    # draw using Tkinter
    root = Tk()
    canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=300)
    canvas.create_polygon(*coords)
    canvas.pack()
    root.mainloop()

draw(2, 4, 5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
from turtle import color, begin_fill, forward, left, end_fill, done
from math import acos, degrees

def triangle_exists(a, b, c):
    """Return True iff there exists a triangle with sides a, b, c."""
    return a + b > c and b + c > a and c + a > b

def triangle_angle(a, b, c):
    """Return the angle (in degrees) opposite the side of length a in the
    triangle with sides a, b, c."""
    # See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines
    return degrees(acos((b ** 2 + c ** 2 - a ** 2) / (2.0 * b * c)))

def draw_triangle(a, b, c):
    """Draw a triangle with sides of lengths a, b, and c."""
    assert(triangle_exists(a, b, c))
    color('black', 'yellow')
    begin_fill()
    forward(c)
    left(180 - triangle_angle(b, c, a))
    forward(a)
    left(180 - triangle_angle(c, a, b))
    forward(b)
    end_fill()
    done()

>>> draw_triangle(400, 350, 200)
```

[image]

Comment: Is the module turtle installed by default or is it external? plus that module creates nothing *practically* useful as turtle is only used to teach programming for *kids* ...

Comment: @KDawG: [`turtle` is built-in to Python](http://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html). And what's wrong with teaching programming to kids? The OP may well be a kid learning to program!

Answer (score -1):

If you are plotting by using the (x,y) coordinates of the vertices, you have at least three continuous degrees of freedom: 2 for choosing the location of vertex A, and one more for the direction from A to B.  Then, there is a binary choice of clockwise or counter-clockwise order for the labeling of the vertices.

If you don't care which of these to use, then you can put A at (0,0), B at (0, c), and then solve for the intersection of two circles: radius a centered at B, and radius b centered as A.

```
x² + y² = b² 
(x - c)² + y² = a² .... subtract these to eliminate y² 
(x - c)² - x² = a² - b²
-2cx + c² = a² - b²
2cx = c² + b² - a²
x = (c² + b² - a²)/(2c)
y = ± √[ b² - x² ] .... choose - for clockwise, + for counter-clockwise
```

Now you have three points A=(0,0), B=(0,c) and C=(x,y) with the desired opposite side lengths a,b,c respectively.  If you need the angles, use the Law of Cosines from trig:

```
c² = a² + b² - 2ab(cos C)
2ab(cos C) = a² + b² - c²
C = cos⁻¹[ (a² + b² - c²)/(2ab) ]
```

The same pattern applies to solving for A and B.  Those are the interior angles.  For turtles, the turning angle is exterior angle, so start at point A, move (c) in any direction, turn (180-B), then move (a), then turn (180-B), then move (b).